# Is there a list of Microsoft Apps made by Microsoft on their store?

Tags: windows, search, windows-store-app, microsoft, microsoft-store

### Problem

- Microsoft Store's UI lacks specificity: an absence of filters for
  searching.

*Luckily, you can search via author by clicking on the author of an app.*

- Searching by Microsoft *(as author)* returns endless bloat due to wallpaper packages.

However, there are valuable apps I've found buried within this list.

### Evidence (left - search apps by author, right - wallpaper bloat):

[image: Left - search apps by author, right - wallpaper bloat]

## Question:

Is there a comprehensive app list for applications published by Microsoft that would be available for viewing?

Otherwise, is there a way of querying the Microsoft Store through the desktop application otherwise via the website to search ONLY for apps?

Comment: What's wrong with searching the Store using keyword?

Comment: Because I want to know what apps Microsoft has uploaded to the store that they've made, a keyword search shows apps from anyone.

Comment: Search then for "Microsoft".

Comment: That would show all apps with Microsoft in the name (most of them not published by Microsoft), and might not show some apps published by Microsoft that do not have Microsoft in the app name.

Comment: See [List All Available Microsoft Store Apps in Intune with PowerShell](https://ourcloudnetwork.com/list-all-available-microsoft-store-apps-in-intune-with-powershell/).

Comment: I don't know why this was closed in the 1st place as it was clear and got also an answer, proving it was clear. The edits though make it less clear now, IMO, still voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search `Microsoft Corporation` and then use the **Filters** button on the side to only show **Apps** or whatever category you want to see, no Themes.

[image: Filters]

You can also try searching `Microsoft Corporation -personalization`.

If you scroll very far, you might eventually see some apps not published by Microsoft that somehow have sneaked in but those are obvious and near the bottom of the list. This is the best way to filter out wallpapers/themes.

Comment: This is it! Thank you @MC10!!!

Comment: I was filtering by publisher first. This removes the options to then utilise other filters. The answer was as simple as just searching the publisher in the search bar first.